# Symfony4: DataFixtures with foreign keys and truncate / resetting autoincrement values

Tags: foreign-keys, symfony4

I try to generate database data with symfony's respective doctrines DataFixture feature.

If I load the data several times by doing this:

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

It does empty my db and generates the data anew. However it doesn't set back the autoincrement values. 
If I run this command with the option --purge-with-truncate it does just that, but then I get complaint about my foreign key constraints:

```
    $ php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test -n --purge-with-truncate
> purging database

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 68:

An exception occurred while executing 'TRUNCATE property':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`my_db_name`.`user_property`, CONSTRAINT `fk_property_name` FOREIGN KEY (`propert
y_name`) REFERENCES `my_db_name`.`property` (`name`))
```

So yes of course I had added the dependencies, when I created my fixtures in three different classes. The Entity UserProperty is depending both on User and Property.

Therefore I implemented the  DependentFixtureInterface by adding the following method to my UserPropertyFixtures class:

```
public function getDependencies()
{
    return [
        UserFixtures::class,
        PropertyFixtures::class,
    ];
}
```

Am I missing something or was it never to work?

Is there another option to reset the autoincrement values?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have found out there is no solution for this. 
I found a solution for not to refer to a certain id for test values. DataFixtures make it possible that you create "named" values, to which you can refer in other fixtures.

However if you want to truncate your table and are using foreign keys you have to do the DROP and CREATE manually in the proper order. 
Not nice....

If someone still has a solution I would be still interested.

Comment: Somebody described a solution here, but I didn't get it to work in Symfony4
https://coderwall.com/p/staybw/workaround-for-1701-cannot-truncate-a-table-referenced-in-a-foreign-key-constraint-using-doctrine-fixtures-load-purge-with-truncate

Comment: There seems to be initiative to fix it in doctrine, but it is still not solved:
https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/pull/272

Comment: Somebody tried to hack their own solution so I leave the  link here: https://coderwall.com/p/staybw/workaround-for-1701-cannot-truncate-a-table-referenced-in-a-foreign-key-constraint-using-doctrine-fixtures-load-purge-with-truncate

Comment: Note: the solution in the link doesn't work with mariadb!